# Filter id with multiples arrays inside object remove item onClick

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, next.js

I have the following object with multiple arrays. I'm trying to filter to get the id to remove the item in onClick. What I've tried is this far, but the error filters.

The error message is `filter is not a function`

The `filters` is where save state the object below

**Function handleRemoveItem**

```
 const handleDeleteFilter = (itemId: string) => {
      const entries = Object.entries(filters).map((s) =>
      s[1].map((e: any) => filters.filter(() => e.id !== itemId))
    )
  }
```

**Object called Filters**

```
{
  "services": [
    {
      "id": "1b975589-7111-46a4-b433-d0e3c0d7c08c",
      "name": "PIX"
    },
    {
      "id": "91d4637e-a17f-4b31-8675-c041fe06e2ad",
      "name": "Rendimentos"
    }
  ],
  "accountTypes": [
    {
      "id": "1f34205b-2e5a-430e-982c-5673cbdb3a68",
      "name": "Conta digital"
    }
  ],
  "channels": [
    {
      "id": "875f8350-073e-4a20-be20-38482a86892b",
      "name": "Chat"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Button onClick**

```
<div
          id={filter.id}
          key={index}
          onClick={() => handleDeleteFilter(filter.id)}
        >
    <span>Remove</span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple procedural approach.

```js
const keys = Object.keys(filters);
for (let i=0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  const filterArray = filters[keys[i]];
  for (let j=0; j<filterArray.length; j++) {
    if (filterArray[j].id === itemId) {
      delete filters[keys[i]];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error is that the `filters` object is not an array, but an object and thus does not have a `.filter` method.

The way to fix the syntax error would be by taking Object.entries() of filters as you do in the precious line;

```
const handleDeleteFilter = (itemId: string) => {
  const entries = Object.entries(filters).map((s) =>
    s[1].map((e: any) => Object.entries(filters).filter(() => e.id !== itemId))
  )
}
```

However, i don't think this is the best or most readable approach for you.You state your goal as *"trying to filter to get the id to remove the item in onClick"*. If you want to remove the object with id equal to `itemId` from any / all of the arrays in the filters object (services, accountTypes, channels), then try something more on the lines of;

```
type IFilter = {id: string, name: string};

type IFilters = { services: IFilter[], accounTypes: IFilter[], channels: IFilter[] }

// Remove an @id from a @filter
const removeId = (filter: IFilter[], id: string): IFilter[] => filter.filter(entry => entry.id.includes(id));

// Remove @id from all @filters
const removeItemFromFilterObj = (id: string, filters: IFilters): IFilters => ({    
    services: removeId(filters.services, id),
    accounTypes: removeId(filters.accounTypes, id),
    channels: removeId(filters.channels, id);
});
```